# Can we write C# console application and ASP.NET Core MVC web application using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, iis, aws-lambda

I am a bit new to AWS Lambda, and i am not sure if it is a deployment framework where we can host ASP.NET Core MVC web application inside it? or can call .NET Core console application? it is a hosting services. For example currently we have the following 2 main components:-

1. ASP.NET Core Console application which runs on schedule basis using Windows tasks scheduler.
2. ASP.NET Core MVC web application which is hosted inside IIS to host some API End Points.

So if we want to use AWS Lambda, in the above 2 components, which section/s it will replace ? For example for the first point, will it replace the Console application or the windows task scheduler? and for the second point, will it replace the ASP.NET Core MVC web application or IIS? Or AWS Lambda will not replace any thing but will/can integrate with the above components?

Thanks in advance for any help. and sorry if i do not have much knowledge in AWS Lambda.

Comment: I guess your console app is accessing on-premises resources such as files in local folders or local services? One of the challenges will be getting network connectivity from the AWS compute to your on-prem resources. So even if you can run your console app you need to consider how much of this process you can move to the cloud

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The console application will integrate with SharePoint Online using Client-Side Object Module + will integrate with local 3rd party system.. so there is not any connectivity issue in our case..

Comment: So the local 3rd party system is also a public cloud service? It sounds like you need to simply get in and start experimenting.

Comment: If you are writing a MVC app, then you do not need to use an AWS Lambda function to invoke AWS Services. You can invoke many AWS Services using the AWS SDK for .NET from a NET class.

Answer (score 2):

In short, AWS Lambda or Azure Functions are special types of application models for the cloud based solutions, not traditional console or web apps. Don't make any attempt to associate them with each others, as they differ significantly.

> Such cloud applications won't take place of tradition app models any time soon, as not everyone is moving to the cloud.

For example, if you want scheduled jobs on AWS, then [Lambda and CloudWatch can work together](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html).

However, to host REST API on AWS you do have multiple options, such as

- [Serverless API with Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html)
- [Traditional web app on Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-core-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply... now our customer want to use AWS Lambda, while i am proposing to implement the functionalities using ASP.NET core Console application (for running schedule jobs + long running processes)+ ASP.NET Core MVC (for hosting API endpoints) ... so should i change my proposed functionalities to be completely replaced by AWS Lambda ? Second question; Can i write background jobs + REST API end points in AWS Lambda? if the answer is yes then can i use ASP.NET to write these inside Lambda
 ?

Comment: @johnGu you still attack the requirements in the traditional mindset, and that prevents you from utilizing native cloud services. For example, schedule jobs (long running code) in traditional app models are quite suitable to be Windows services (not console apps), but they are quite suitable for AWS Lambda or Azure Functions as the cloud services allow you to trigger the code in several ways (such as timers). However, hosting REST API on cloud is too flexible and you can either use AWS Lambda/Azure Functions (trigger by HTTP requests) or the traditional web app model.

Comment: @johnGu updated the answer to include several references to AWS documentation on scheduled jobs and REST API.

Comment: @Lexi Li i am reading more about Lambda, and there is a lot of articles which is saying that Lambda is not suitable for long running processes as they will restart after 15 minutes.. is this correct?

Comment: @johnGu this is correct - they have a small run time. But the idea is that they are triggered by Event - If you want to make use of Serverless Cloud computing you have to think in an Event driven structure - Events fire and trigger smaller components to operate. 'Long Running' can mean a lot of things. If your app has a lot of components that run in sequence, you can divide those into different lambdas and trigger off ... many things. Database updates, s3 inserts ect. Cloud native architecture is a **very** different game

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: I mistakenly was under the impression that C# needed a custom docker image. This is not the case, there are provided images for C# in Lambda*

Theoretically, you could make lambdas your controllers in an MVC application - in fact its actually a good design decision to do so. However, given ASP's nature this can become a little tricky first time.  They would have to be behind API endpoints but with a little work in the configuraiton you can distribute the controllers across lambdas.

The scheduled tasks are perfect for lambda as well, but again - not c# native.

There is not any default Windows images in AWS.  Honestly, if you are going to do a c# ASP app you may want to consider Azure instead, as it natively interacts with C# and ASP where you have to hack the options together in AWS

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but still i am not sure about these points `For example for the first point, will it replace the Console application or the windows task scheduler? and for the second point, will it replace the ASP.NET Core MVC web application or IIS? Or AWS Lambda will not replace any thing but will/can integrate with the above components?` can you advice?

Comment: "but you have to use a custom docker"? This page says nothing about Docker, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-cli-publish.html Also if you claimed "C# is not yet native language for lambdas" you'd better provide some more evidence, as the official AWS documentation does present C# as a native language just like any other.

Comment: I stand corrected - I was using outdated information. i will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @johnGu most likely it will integrate with, not replace - but I believe it is entirely possible to use Lambda (Or otherlike Azure Functions) to replace some of those components if you write the hooks correctly. I am not aware of how to do that, but it should be possible.